# When calling NSSet's setByAddingX methods, which set's objects win a tie?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsset

I bring this up because objects that compare the same with isEquals: aren't necessarily identical.  Some (many) objects only compare certain properties to determine equality.

That makes the exact behavior of the following NSSet methods important:

```
setByAddingObject:
setByAddingObjectsFromArray:
setByAddingObjectsFromSet:
```

The documentation does not specify what happens when the receiver and the parameter contain equivalent objects.  Will the resulting NSSet contain the object from the receiver, or the object from the "other" parameter?

Note that in NSMutableSet, it DOES specify the behavior of its add methods--objects will NOT be added if an "equal" object already exists in the set.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tested this with the following code.  SomeClass is defined such that propertyA is the only property considered in hash and isEquals:

```
SomeClass *objectA = [[[SomeClass alloc] init] autorelease];
objectA.propertyA = @"test";
objectA.propertyB = @"objectA";

SomeClass *objectB = [[[SomeClass alloc] init] autorelease];
objectB.propertyA = @"test";
objectB.propertyB = @"objectB";

NSSet *setA = [NSSet setWithObject:objectA];
NSSet *setB = [NSSet setWithObject:objectB];
NSSet *setC = [setA setByAddingObjectsFromSet:setB];

NSLog(@"Set A\n%@", [setA description]);
NSLog(@"Set B\n%@", [setB description]);
NSLog(@"Set C\n%@", [setC description]);
```

The output when running this code is:

```
2011-03-03 16:35:15.041 temp[50311:207] Set A
{(
    {SomeClass propertyA:test propertyB:objectA}
)}
2011-03-03 16:35:15.041 temp[50311:207] Set B
{(
    {SomeClass propertyA:test propertyB:objectB}
)}
2011-03-03 16:35:15.042 temp[50311:207] Set C
{(
    {SomeClass propertyA:test propertyB:objectA}
)}
```

This demonstrates that the newly created NSSet will contain objects from the RECEIVER in the case that the parameter contains equivalent objects.

**EDIT** - I'm marking this as the answer, because it directly answers the question at hand.  I would however, point out Peter's answer below and the concerns he voices.  This behavior **is** undocumented and as such, while it's extremely unlikely these core classes will change in this regard, it's worth pointing out that risk.  If you write code assuming this behavior it is **possible** that it will break in a future release.  Caveat emptor.

Comment: This isn't documented, though, so you shouldn't rely on this behavior. (An old version of NSMutableSet's docs does cover adding the same object, but not an equal object. NSSet's says nothing.) A set with a different implementation (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW34) may prefer the object you try to add over the object it already has. You could encounter that in another OS version or in the very same process. Don't rely on undocumented implementation details like this.

Comment: I agree with the comment about not relying on undocumented behavior, but I stand behind this answer.  It answers the question, and it is correct.  It is also extremely unlikely that Apple will change the functionality of these classes in such a fundamental way.  Knowledge is power, do what you will with it.

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation of NSMutableSet's `addObject:` method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableSet/addObject%3a) used to cover a similar case:

> If `anObject` is already present in the set, this method has no effect on either the set or `anObject`.

But, as you can see from following the link, the current version doesn't even say that. And even that statement really only covers trying to add the same object; it does not specifically address adding a different but equal object.

Relying on observed but not documented behavior is dangerous, not just because it can change between OS versions, but also because it can change within the very same process. That's because NSSet is a [class cluster](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW34), meaning there may be multiple implementations. Which one you get depends on how you create the set; there is no way to ensure that a specific implementation will be chosen or even exist.*

That's because it shouldn't matter. Every one of the clustered subclasses presents the same behavior as defined in the cluster's interface and documentation. (If it ever doesn't, that's a bug and you should [report it](https://bugreport.apple.com/).) Given that all the subclasses do effectively the same things, it shouldn't matter which one you get an instance of.

The same principle applies to your objects. They're equal! For that reason, it shouldn't matter which one is in the set. If it does matter, then they are not truly equal, and you need to make the objects' definition of equality more rigid. (Don't forget to update both `isEqual:` *and* `hash`.)

Depending on what you're using the set for, you may want to take that even farther and ensure that no two equal objects can exist. To do this, move the ownership, maintenance, and use of the set into the member objects' class, and have it always return a matching object instead of creating a new one whenever possible and appropriate.

*And even if you could choose one of the implementations, there's no guarantee that it'd have the behavior you observed forever—it could, and Murphy says probably will, be different in another OS version.

Comment: @Peter - Hey Peter, point well made about relying on undocumented behavior.  I have a variety of problems with the notion of isEqual:.  It's really overloaded for two different purposes.  1) Are these two object instances exactly equal and 2) object identity.  In database terms, we're using the same formula to act as our unique key in a table, as well as to determine if two rows are identical.  Those are two different things.  Since Cocoa classes already assume isEquals: is used for object identity, I do not try to use it for strict instance equivalence.  Your point stands though, just saying.

Comment: @DougW: No, Cocoa does not “assume `isEqual:` is used for object identity”. It assumes it's used for testing equality. The default definition of `isEqual:` is object identity, but you can *and are meant to* change that in your classes where two or more instances can be equal. You need to override `isEqual:` (and `hash`) to match your definition of the objects' equality. See the definition of `isEqual:` in the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isEqual:

Comment: @Peter - We're talking about different identities.  I don't mean its memory address.  I mean if I have two objects representing User A, they may have different property values--maybe one is newer than the other.  That does not, however, mean I suddenly want two User As in my collections.  Therefor, isEqual: will return YES if their user ids are the same, but doesn't care about their last login time.  NSSet does assumes that isEqual: describes a notion of equality at a higher level than strict equivalence... otherwise there would be no need for a method, it could be checked through reflection.

Comment: @DougW: Ah. So, why would there be two objects for user A? Why not uniquify them based on the user ID, and, in the example of the last login time, have a LoginRecord (or some such thing) that contains the login time and knows a User?

Comment: @Peter - Yeah, in many cases we do exactly that, or some variation. We've run into a number of cases though, where a controller pulls out a few objects from a set, modifies some attributes based on user interaction, and then wants to replace them. In simple cases we can use a dictionary keyed on the id, but there are some cases where a single id isn't sufficient to define uniqueness. The issue is that NSSet assumes isEqual: as a "Candidate Key" for these objects just like a database would, which is a notion a little bit different than what most people think of when implementing isEqual:.

Comment: @Peter - There are certainly ways we can work around this, I just wanted to point out that isEqual: is a bit overloaded for different purposes.  No argument with your main point, and I appreciate your responses!